# Delete from Nautilus as root - where is my trash?

Tags: ubuntu, trash

I run Nautilus as root to access folders like /var/www. I now deleted a file by pressing the del key and was wondering where I can find the trash to really have it removed completely?

OS: Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: **Open `trash://` in Nautilus.** You don't need to know where it is located physically; just use "Empty Trash".

---

Longer version:

- If the file was on the same filesystem as your (root's) home directory:
  **`~/.local/share/Trash/`**
- If it was on a separate filesystem, and `<rootdir>/.Trash/` exists and is mode 01777:
  **`<rootdir>/.Trash/<uid>/`**
- If it was on a separate filesystem, but `<rootdir>/.Trash/` doesn't exist or has wrong permissions:
  **`<rootdir>/.Trash-<uid>/`**

Here, *<rootdir>* is the root directory of that filesystem. In this case, it's `/`, so simply **`/.Trash`** and **`/.Trash-<uid>/`**.

*<uid>* is the user ID – in this case, `0` for root.

So the directory you are looking for is **`/root/.local/share/Trash/`**.

Answer (score 0):

The root trash is apparently here: /root/.Trash

According to a Google Search anyway...